# Defining your own key path operators in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-coding

Is it possible to define your own key path operators, such as @avg, @sum, etc…

Comment: I have to keep fighting the urge to send `cocoa` questions over to the cooking site...

Comment: +1 this is a really fascinating question; one that I've never thought to ask, but one that has revealed some really interesting information. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: Kinda. You can override `valueForKeyPath:` to intercept your custom operator or forward on to `super`, but that can be problematic (I'll leave the explanation to that as an exercise to the reader).

Long answer: Yes you can, but it relies on using private behavior (not private api).

After some neat introspection of `NSArray`, I found some private methods:

```
_distinctUnionOfSetsForKeyPath:
_distinctUnionOfObjectsForKeyPath:
_distinctUnionOfArraysForKeyPath:
_unionOfSetsForKeyPath:
_unionOfArraysForKeyPath:
_unionOfObjectsForKeyPath:
_minForKeyPath:
_maxForKeyPath:
_countForKeyPath:
_avgForKeyPath:
_sumForKeyPath:
```

Well, neat!  Those methods seem to match the operators you can use with collections: `@sum`, `@min`, `@max`, `@distinctUnionOfObjects`, etc.  The `@` has been replaced with an underscore and we've got `ForKeyPath:` appended.

So it would seem that we can create a new method to match the appropriate signature and we're good to go.

So:

```
@interface NSArray (CustomOperator)

- (id) _fooForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;

@end

@implementation NSArray (CustomOperator)

- (id) _fooForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
  //keyPath will be what comes after the keyPath.  In this example, it will be "self"
  return @"Hello world!";
}

@end

NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [array valueForKeyPath:@"@foo.SELF"]); //logs "Hello world!"
```

It works, but I'm not sure I would rely on this, since it relies on an implementation detail that could change in the future.

Comment: Override `-valueForKey:` instead though I would. Read the docs on how NSDictionary implements it.

Comment: @Mike in the long run it's probably stabler, but the problem with overriding is that these operators are usually only useful on collections, and subclassing collections kinda sucks. :(

Comment: Nice find Dave! However, it does seem a bi brittle as you said. Why do you think that overriding valueForKeyPath: is more dangerous?

Comment: @Fernando: subclassing collections is tricky compared to a category and I haven't played around with it to know what would be involved.  Are there specific edge cases you'd have to code for? I don't know. The category approach, though seemingly brittle, just seems simpler to me.

Comment: You could also make use of Matt Gallagher's ["Supersequent Implementation"](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html) technique for categories to basically allow you to just categorize `-valueForKey:` on `NSArray`. Catch your own custom key path operators, and send anything else back up to the "supersequent" implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by overriding `valueForKeyPath:` and doing your own custom logic in there, but there's no framework support for it.